# Use ipdb instead of pdb with py.test --pdb option

Tags: python, pytest, pdb, ipdb

I want to use [ipdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipdb) instead of [pdb](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) with [py.test --pdb](http://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/contents.html) option. Is this possible? If so, how?

Clearly, I can use `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` in the code but that requires to run the test, watch it fail, open a file, find the point of failure in said file, write the above line, re-run the tests. Lots of hassle if I could have something that by passes all of that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried [pytest-ipdb](https://github.com/mverteuil/pytest-ipdb)?

Looks like it's exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: It was discontinued in favour of [pdb++](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdbpp/) which is good. I ended up using using pdb++.

Answer (score 25):

Use this option to set custom debugger:

> --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb

It can also be included in pytest.ini using `addopts`:

```
[pytest]
addopts = "--pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb"
```

Comment: in a file pytest.ini: [pytest]
addopts = --pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb

Comment: So glad to find this! Note you also need the `--pdb` flag

Comment: If you have a more recent setup, you may need:

`[tool.pytest.ini_options] addopts = "--pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb"`