# iPython features in pytest debugging sessions

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, ipython, read-eval-print-loop, ipdb

I'm struggling with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/8.0.x/) configuration. I would like to:

1. use `breakpoint()` wherever I want in my tests to start debugging sessions,
2. in that case, be able to enter multi line inputs (several lines of code in a row that should be run simultaneously),
3. have colors both for `Pytest` output (`PASSED` in green, for instance) and for the loosely coupled debugging code I'm writing (what follows `>ipdb` in the screenshot below),
4. have a clean and readable indentation in my `breakpoint()` inputs,
5. have tab completion like in `iPython`,
6. have the same environment in the debugging sessions started on failure with the `--pdb` flag.

(from highest to lowest priority)

#### In short, I'd like to improve that:

[image]

Here is the context: I'm doing [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and I'd like to have the most comfortable working environment.

For now, I've set `PYTHONBREAKPOINT` to `"IPython.terminal.debugger.set_trace"` ([doc](https://pytest.org/en/8.0.x/how-to/failures.html#setting-breakpoints)) and I run `pytest` with `--pdbcls=IPython.terminal.debugger:Pdb` (cf. [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39162569/use-ipdb-instead-of-pdb-with-py-test-pdb-option)).

I haven't given [bpython](https://github.com/bpython/bpython) a try, should I consider this alternative?